# c# SSIS error binary code not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, soap, ssis, sharepoint-2007

I'm using SOAP in a SSIS package to grab rows from a sharepoint list.  The list is 2007 so I can't use the regular share point connector.

The script says it builds successfully yet I have the error "The binary code for the script is not found. Please open the script"....  I've been thru this and google and I think I've gone code blind, I just can't see what I'm doing wrong....

code as follows:

```
>#region Namespaces
>using System;
>using System.Data;
>using System.Net;
>using System.Security;
>using System.Xml;
>using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
>using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
>using SC_45b2900a2cc74c6b8d017e26b0213177.spSource;
>#endregion

 public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    string userId = Variables.UserId;
    string passWord = Variables.PassWord;
    DateTime asOfDate = Variables.LastDate;

    SecureString encryptPassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in passWord.ToCharArray())
    {
        encryptPassword.AppendChar(c);
    }

    const string LISTNAME = @"BPOS Dedicated";
```

> ```
>    const string DateQuery = @"<Where>
>                            <Or>
>                                <Geq>
>                                    <FieldRef Name='Created'/>
>                                    <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>[LASTDATE]</Value>
>                                </Geq>
>                                <Geq>
>                                    <FieldRef Name='Modified'/>
>                                    <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>[LASTDATE]</Value>
>                                </Geq>
>                            </Or>
>                        </Where>";
> ```

```
    System.Net.NetworkCredential netPass = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userId, encryptPassword);

    SC_45b2900a2cc74c6b8d017e26b0213177.com.microsoft.msonline.Lists webRefSvc = new SC_45b2900a2cc74c6b8d017e26b0213177.com.microsoft.msonline.Lists();
    webRefSvc.Credentials = netPass;

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

    XmlNode ndQuery = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Query", "");
    XmlNode ndViewFields = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ViewFields", "");
    XmlNode ndQueryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "QueryOptions", "");

    ndQueryOptions.InnerXml = "<IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns><DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc>";
```

> ```
>    ndViewFields.InnerXml = @"<FieldRef Name='ID' /> 
>                             <FieldRef Name='Request Type' />";
> ```

```
    ndQuery.InnerXml = DateQuery.Replace("[LASTDATE]", asOfDate.ToString("s"));

    XmlNode ndListitems = webRefSvc.GetListItems(LISTNAME, null, ndQuery, ndViewFields, null, ndQueryOptions, null);

    foreach (XmlNode item in ndListitems)
    {
        RowBuffer.AddRow();

        int intConv = 0;

        if (item["ID"].Value != null)
        {
            string idString = item["ID"].Value.ToString();

            if (int.TryParse(idString, out intConv))
            {
                RowBuffer.ID = intConv;
            }
        }

        RowBuffer.RequestType = item["Request Type"].Value.ToString();

    }

    RowBuffer.SetEndOfRowset();
}
```

Comment: Is that the entire script? I'm assuming it's in a class definition?

Comment: I also assume you've tried rebuilding and are making sure to exit the new instance of Visual Studio opened when you go to edit the script?

Comment: Did you copy and paste the SSIS code namespace from a separate instance of code?  If the GUID is different, it will throw a similar error.